# Creating scala.collection.immutable.vector in Java and adding elements to it

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use scala List directly in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524868/can-i-use-scala-list-directly-in-java)

Can someone help me with creating scala vector within Java and adding say 50 elements to it? Thanks

Comment: I was trying the following but doesnt seem to work.       import scala.collection.immutable.Vector                        Vector<Integer> v = Vector.empty();
         
for(int i = 1; i <51; i++) 
         {
            v.appendBack(i);
         }

Comment: ohh..Got that solved..it should have been v = v.appendBack(i);

Comment: If you find a good solution, you should enter an answer to your own question rather than using comments.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this efficiently, you'll need to use a *builder*:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector;
import scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder;

public class VectorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        VectorBuilder<Integer> vb = new VectorBuilder<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            vb.$plus$eq(Integer.valueOf(i));
        Vector<Integer> vec = vb.result();
        System.out.println("vec = " + vec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector;

Vector v = Vector.empty();
for(int i = 1; i <51; i++)
{
    v = v.appendBack(i);
}
```